# If doesn't work inside a modal

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

It works fine if the HTML is inside the DOM. But I have an AJAX-modal (magnific Popup) and there the script doesn't work.

The class "no-touch" won't be removed, any ideas what I have to change that it works inside the modal as well?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  win_w = $(window).width();
  win_h = $(window).height();
  if (/Mobi/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $(".mgu-profil-selection__food5, .mgu-profil-selection__food6").removeClass("no-touch");
  }
})
```

Comment: The modal is being rendered after the DOM loads completely, you have to look for the element... What is i.test() (`/Mobi/i.test(navigator.userAgent)`) returning? how is the test being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is only executed on page load, you should also run this after the ajax request

You can assign callbacks to your magnific Popup (see [docs](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html))

```
function check() {
  win_w = $(window).width();
  win_h = $(window).height();

  if (/Mobi/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $(".mgu-profil-selection__food5, .mgu-profil-selection__food6").removeClass("no-touch");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  check();
})


$('.image-link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image',
  callbacks: {
    ajaxContentAdded: function() {
      // Ajax content is loaded and appended to DOM
      // run check function again
      check();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks. The function ist loaded, perfect, but the classes not. Tried '.mgu-modal.mgu-profil-selection__food5' but no success